# How to show that this particular card game is a martingale?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-expectation, martingale

An ordinary deck of cards is randomly shuffled and then the cards are exposed one at a time.

At some time before all the cards have been exposed you must say “next”, and if the next card
exposed is a spade then you win and if not then you lose.

For any strategy, show that at the moment you call “next” the conditional probability that you win is equal to the conditional probability that the last card is spade.

Conclude from this that the probability of winning is 1/4 for all strategies.

Hint: one approach is to show that the proportion of spades remaining is a martingale.

My attempt to answer this question:
Let $X_n$ indicate if the nth card is spade and $Z_n$ be the proportion of spades in the remaining cards after the nth card. Thus $E|Z_n| < \infty$ But how to prove $\{Z_n\}$ is a martingale by computing $\mathbb{E}[Z_n| Z_{n-1},\dots,Z_1] = Z_{n-1}$

I don't know how to answer this question.

Note: This question is taken from the book titled "Stochastic Processes" written by Professor S. Ross(University of California)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$Z_{n-1}$ is the proportion of spades left in the deck before we make the $n^{th}$ draw; therefore, it is equal to the probability that the next card is a spade.  Let us assume there are $k$ spades left in the deck and $K$ total cards left in the deck, so $Z_{n-1} = k/K$.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}Z_n &=& {k-1\over K-1}p\left(Z_n = {k-1\over K-1}\right)+{k\over K-1}p\left(Z_n = {k\over K-1}\right) \\
&=& {k-1\over K-1}{k \over K}+{k\over K-1}{K-k\over K}\\
&=&{k^2 - 1\cdot k  +kK - k^2 \over (K-1)K} \\
&=&{(K-1)k \over (K-1)K} \\
&=& {k \over K}
\end{eqnarray}$$

as desired.

Since $1/4$ of the cards in the deck are spades, before the game starts, the probability of winning is $1/4$. As there is nothing we can do to affect the probability of drawing a spade on the next card, and the probability process is a martingale, no strategy can affect our initial probability of winning.  This is a consequence of the [Martingale Stopping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem).

Comment: But how to conclude from this that the probability of winning is $\frac14$ for all strategies?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that...  I'll update the answer.